# bitcoin core 0.13.1: Inconsistent getbalance result from RPC

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc

I have a node which is giving inconsistent results from RPC:

```
$ bitcoin-cli getbalance 
0.01647763
$ bitcoin-cli getbalance "*" 1
1.90937153
$ bitcoin-cli getbalance "" 1
1.90937153
$ bitcoin-cli getbalance * 1
0.00000000
$ bitcoin-cli listaccounts
{
  "": 1.90937153
}
```

Not sure how can I interpret this. Does my wallet have 0, 0.01647763 or 1.90937153? [Documentation](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#getbalance) for getbalance says that if you don't pass any arguments, the defaults are * (all accounts) and 1, but when I specify those arguments, the result is not the same.

What are the real defaults when not specifying arguments to `getbalance`?

Comment: Is your shell replacing `*` with something else? What happens if you run `echo getbalance * 1` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think I've hit a bitcoin-core bug that may happen in weird circumstances (such as when trying to send a transaction which the node refuses to send, by returning a "rejected" error code). After I restarted the server, the transaction showed up in the bitcoin network, and the `getbalance` RPC calls started to be consistent again.